# Multiple APK for different devices

Tags: android, google-play

I developed an app that works on most phones starting API 16, the problem is that in LG G2 it only works on API 20 and higher..

Is there any way I can do this separation in the google play store?

Thanks,
Dani

Comment: Do you understand why it is API 20 only the LG G2? Is there a way you could possibly sniff that feature or device bug and include a workaround in your application?

Comment: No , there is no workaround..

Comment: I would consider posting a question about the core technical issue -- how to work around the issue on the LG G2.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using multiple APK support.

> Multiple APK support is a feature on Google Play that allows you to
>   publish different APKs for your application that are each targeted to
>   different device configurations. Each APK is a complete and
>   independent version of your application, but they share the same
>   application listing on Google Play and must share the same package
>   name and be signed with the same release key. This feature is useful
>   for cases in which your application cannot reach all desired devices
>   with a single APK.

You can support different platform versions with each APK, which will allow you to use API 20 and API 16 as you request.

However, keep in mind this recommendation from Google:

> Using a single APK to support different configurations is always the
>   best practice, because it makes the path for application updates
>   simple and clear for users (and also makes your life simpler by
>   avoiding development and publishing complexity).

You will need to configure your APK's platform API levels in your AndroidManifest.xml and upload the published APK **in Advanced Mode** in the Google Play Developer Console. This means setting up multiple AndroidManifests, configuring them to included different 'uses-sdk' elements and uploading multiple APK.

All of the filters that are valid for Multiple APK publishing are listed in this Google-provided guide:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html

While this is possible, I would advise you to avoid it if you can because maintaining it is not fun or easy.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I uploaded a second APK with minsdk=20..
But there is only one list for supported devices..

I want to include the LG G2 device only for the apk that is minsdk=20

Comment: I am afraid that at this time, Google offers no facility to support anything better than what i posted. Other options (multiple applications with filters) exist but are highly non-optimal.